# How can I hide the 'id' attribute in Loopback explorer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, loopbackjs, strongloop

Is it possible to hide the id attribute in a method in swagger-ui generated by explorer in Strongloop Loopback?
I don want the user to create a new resource and send the id attribute. I know that if the user send the id it can be ignored but I want to hide it in the explorer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to hide the 'id' attribute, [you need declare this field as hidden.](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Hiddenproperties)

In YOUR_MODEL.json file:

```
{
  "name": "YOUR_MODEL",
  .
  .
  .
  "properties": {
     // your custom properties
  },
  "hidden": ["id"], // this attribute specifies which attributes need to be hidden
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Be aware when a property declared as hidden:

1. It's not exposed to the user
2. Although hidden, if user sends provides a value with this property, **the property won't be ignored by default, and will be handled with provided values**. hence, need to be ignored manually.

For instance, if we have 'User' model as follows:

```
{
  "name": "User",
  .
  .
  .
  "properties": {
     "id": "string",
     "name": "string",
     "password": "string",

  },
  "hidden": ["id", "password"],
  .
  .
}
```

`/api/User` GET request will provide list of Users with **only 'name' attribute**

**BUT,** `/api/User` POST with body:

```
{
  "user" : "USER",
  "password": "PASS",
  "id" : "USER_PROVIDED_ID"
}
```

the user provided in the body will be saved with the values in it.